Sci fi novel 20, 30 years old w/ girl from dystopian Earth and giant chittering raccoons. Title may contain "animal companion(s)"
I only vaguely remember this book from possibly as long as thirty years ago; Card sleeve and labeling showed it was in a library at some point.
Main protagonist is female, several worlds involved starting in a dystopian Earth, ending with her somewhere that includes giant raccoon creatures who chitter. The title (I thought) included "companion(s)" and/or "animal companion(s)".
Is not Sheri S. Tepper's The Companions, nor Salvatores' similarly titled novel.

This is all the novels on the ISFDB with "companion" in the title. I can't see any obvious matches to your description. (You need to be logged in to the ISFDB for the search to work)
